# What is 何のこともかんのことも?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **何のこともかんのことも**?

What does かん stand for here?

In context:

The first person says: 「旦那様、それは何のことでやんすか。人ぎきの悪いことだ」,
to which the second person answers, beginning with 何のこともかんのことも and continuing by explaining what the matter was.

Comment: Any context? Would help with a better translation of that phrase as a whole. Anyway I think it's a variation of [なんだかんだ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 日本語

> 何のこともかんのことも

これは、「何のことも彼｛か｝のことも」の「音便変化 *euphonic change*」したものです。

> 「何｛なん｝の彼｛か｝の」が基本形です。

「何の彼の」は、例えば　[この辞書｛じしょ｝](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AE%E5%BD%BC%E3%81%AE-590704)に次｛つぎ｝のような説明｛せつめい｝があります。

> あれこれ。いろいろ。**なんのかんの**。

もちろん「かんの＝彼｛か｝の」は英語では that に相当｛そうとう｝します。「彼」は三人称｛さんにんしょう｝の「彼｛かれ｝」や「彼女｛かのじょ｝」でも使｛つか｝われています。

## English

> 何のことも**かん**のことも

かん in the phrase is the euphonic change from 彼｛か｝ which means "that (indicating something distant from both speaker and listener (in space, time or psychologically), or something understood without naming it directly)".

So the given phrase is expressed as:

> 何のことも彼のことも

This is a set phrase similar to 「何もかも *just about everything*」or 「あれもこれも *this and that*」.

Similar to this phrase, "何のかんの" is more commonly used, which is an euphonic change from "何の彼{か}の" that means "*something or other*".

なんだかんだ and なんやかんや shown by siikamiika are also euphonic changes from 何だ彼｛か｝だ and 何や彼｛か｝や respectively having the same meaning as 何のかんの or 何の彼の.

Comment: +1 for `euphonic change from 彼 ` and  `何もかも`, completely missed those

Comment: +1 for having both Japanese and English, that's really convenient and refreshing

Answer (score 4):

(Your story appears to be [傘の絵](http://minwa.fujipan.co.jp/area/iwate_016/))

A millionaire (the second person) has bought a painting of a woman with an umbrella. The millionaire feels that he has been tricked. When the millionaire sees the salesman who sold the painting (the first person), he is angry at him, to which the salesman responds:

> 旦那様、それは**何のこと**でやんすか。人[聞]{ぎ}きの悪いことだ
>   Master, **what** is that all about? It's disgraceful.

This 何のこと is to what the millionaire answers

> **何のこともかん**のことも、（…）

where 「かん」 is "that" or "other".

「何のこともかんのことも」 could be literally translated to "what and that", but this translation doesn't make much sense in English. Given the context, I would translate it to "Oh, I'll tell you what it's all about!". The important point about this translation is repeating what the salesman said. The function of 「かんのこと」 in this phrase is to say that "there is more to it".

After 「、」 the millionaire continues to explain how the painting didn't "work" as expected.

Comment: 「『何のこと』も『かんのこと』もない」「『何のこと』も『かんのこと』もあるか！」「『何のこと』もへったくれもない」って感じでは・・・つまり「『何のこと？』とかいってとぼけないでくれ」みたいな。。

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ 文脈足りなかった…　物語を読んで編集しました

Comment: @siikamiika Just to clarify, is かんのこと a variant of このこと or is it a different thing altogether?

Comment: @user18849 このこと is a different thing altogether. I think the meaning of this かん is like あれ or あの but it fits better with 何{なん} than those. There are also [なんだかんだ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0) and [なんやかんや](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%82%84) and I think 何のこともかんのことも is derived from them

Comment: @user18849 also see the meanings of the particle [も](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%82)

Comment: We say 何のかの, なんともかんとも, なんだかんだ, but do we also commonly say 何のこともかんのことも? I think it's the author's creative alteration, being playful, isn't it?

Comment: @karlalou I also felt some "playfulness" because the author repeated what the salesman said but I admit that I have little experience of actual usage compared to mackygoo or you. I originally answered because I downvoted an answer claiming that the かん was 間.

Comment: @siikamiika Oh, I see. :)